# Why is apt downloading package list again when updating in 16.04?

Tags: apt, package-management, updates

I don't know if it was problem before or is just a beta thing.

When I run apt update it downloads package list as normal. If I run it again it will download the lists all over again even though there were no updates to packages.

It will download couple of MBs (around 50 megs I think) and on my poor connection will take couple of minutes every time.

Is that a bug on my end? Or on apt?

I updated 15.10 to 16.04.

Solved! It was Virtualbox ppa acting up. Nothing wrong with official repos or apt!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running `apt-get update` redownloads package lists by design - if it didn't, how would it know what packages need updating? To actually upgrade the packages, you need to run `apt-get upgrade`.

Comment: Well check is file changed and if yes download it. In 15.04 process, when no updates were found after, was way faster. 10 seconds vs 10 minutes.